# Aren't Boolean variables always false by default?

Tags: c++, syntax

I had declared a Boolean variable `bool abc;` in a class and thought that it would be false by default. An *if* condition in my program, `if (abc)`, turned out to be true, so I output the value of abc, and saw that it contained the value 55. Is this normal?

Do we always have to assign 'bool abc=false' to be sure that it is false?

Comment: For why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910832/c-why-arent-pointers-initialized-with-null-by-default/1910992#1910992

Comment: [Note that reading an uninitialized variable leads to UB.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259885/why-do-i-see-strange-values-when-i-print-uninitialized-variables/4259991#4259991) Just don't do it.

Comment: An 'interesting' bug that can show up in this situation is both b and !b evaluating to true

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes, you should always initialize your variables.  Until you intimately learn the times when it is and isn't necessary to do so explicitly, you should do it all the time, no matter what.  And by then...well...why stop a good habit?

To initialize a bool to false it's sufficient to default construct it:

```
struct X
{
  bool b;
  X() : b() {}
};
```

Comment: I like to add the explicit boolean literal false (to me that makes it more readable (though technically no different from yours)).

Comment: is the init list necessary?  I thought the expression 'bool b;' did invoke the default ctor...  I've always been confused about how init lists and member variables interact

Comment: @CCJ it is in order to initialize all class members. Unless, you initialize them in-place in the class (like `bool b = false`) - which is mostly only viable for fundamental types.

Comment: @CCJ In 2011, and I think it still holds true for modern C++, fundamental types don't get default initialized unless they're global or static.  There are cases in which they can get initialized outside of those places but its because you've "zero initialized" some structure they are in such as a class or array.  So doing `X x{}` might initialize `x.b` to false.  However, if X has a custom default constructor that does NOT initialize b, it won't be...unless those rules have changed.  Like I suggest, just initialize everything to some value and you don't have to remember all the crap.

Answer (score 75):

Talking about **primitive built-in data types** (bool, char, wchar_t, short, int, long, float, double, long double), according to C++ standard, **only global variables get a default value of zero** if they are not explicitly initialized.

For local variables it's not required for the complier to clean up the content of the memory they are assigned to. A local variable -- if not explicitly initialized -- will contain an arbitrary value.

Comment: Technically it is variables of `static storage duration`  globals are a member of this type of variable.

Comment: C++ will initialize built-in types to zero when they are initialized with a default constructor. Eg. in maps. `std::map<int,bool> m; std::cout << (m[0] ? "true": "false");` will always print `false`.

Comment: It depends on the compiler. Variables are not initialized by default.

Answer (score 9):

Only global variables are assigned 0 (false) by default. Any local variables are given a non-zero garbage value, which would evaluate to true in a boolean variable.

Comment: This is incorrect. Local variables with static (or thread-local) storage duration are also zero-initialized (if it's not a constant).

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You need to either do `bool x=false` or `bool x(false)`. Primitives that are not initialized may have *any* value.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. **Always** initialize your variables before use. Even if the language guarantees that they will have specific values. If you can't force yourself, get a compiler that will complain, and then make yourself do that. :)

However, *don't* initialize values unless it really has a meaning for them to be initialized. For example, if you have a loop like this (I'm not saying this is good code, it's just an example):

```
int i = 0;
while ((i = getNum()) == 5)
{
}
```

Don't initialize `i` to zero like I did. It makes no sense, and while it shuts up the compiler, it introduces the possibility that you'll forget it and then your code will be messed up. If you can force yourself to initialize only at the right times -- no more, no less -- then you'll make debugging a heck of a lot easier, since your [wrong code will *look* wrong even at just a glance](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html).

So, in one line: Never initialize just to prevent the compiler from complaining, but always initialize before use.