# C++11 Why does cout print large integers from a boolean array?

Tags: c++, cout

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool *a = new bool[10];

    cout << sizeof(bool) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(a[0]) << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }

    delete[] a;
}
```

The above code outputs:

```
1
1
112 104 151 0 0 0 0 0 88 1
```

The last line should contain garbage values, but why are they not all 0 or 1? The same thing happens for a stack-allocated array.

Solved: I forgot that sizeof counts bytes, not bits as I thought.

Comment: Are you asking *how* an uninitialized `bool` can hold `88`, or are you asking why *inserting* the unitialized `bool` to `cout` doesn't normalize the data?

Comment: I'm asking how. I'll clarify this.

Comment: note that your program also shows that a `bool` takes up one full byte of storage.

Comment: Yup I just realized that. That explains the confusion. *sigh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(bool)` on your machine returns `1`.

That's 1 *byte*, not 1 *bit*, so the values you show can certainly be present.

Answer (score 8):

You have an array of default-initialized `bool`s. Default-initialization for primitive types entail no initialization, thus they all have indeterminate values.

You can zero-initialize them by providing a pair of parentheses:

```
bool *a = new bool[10]();
```

Booleans are 1-byte integral types so the reason you're seeing this output is probably because that is the data on the stack at that moment that can be viewed with a single byte. Notice how they are values under 255 (the largest number that can be produced from an unsigned 1-byte integer).

OTOH, printing out an indeterminate value is Undefined Behavior, so there really is no logic to consider in this program.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is uninitialized values, different compilers generate different code. [On GCC I see everything as 0](https://ideone.com/LsnZOG) on windows i see junk values.

generally char is the smallest byte addressable- even though bool has 1/0 value- memory access wise it will be a char. Thus you will never see junk value greater than 255

Following initialization (memset fixes the things for you)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool* a = new bool[10];

    memset(a, 0, 10*sizeof(bool));

    cout << sizeof(bool) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(a[0]) << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        bool b = a[i];
        cout << b << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Formally speaking, as pointed out in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4259991/1760583), reading any uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour, which basically means everything is possible.

More practically, the memory used by those bools is filled with what you called garbage. [ostreams operator<<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) inserts booleans via [std::num_put::put()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put), which, if boolalpha is not set, converts the value present to an int and outputs the result.

Answer (score -2):

I do not know why you put a * sign before variable a .
Is it a pointer to point a top element address of the array?

Comment: Please use comments if you need clarification on a question rather than answers.