# Does the standard mandate that the 1-byte storage of a boolean contain only 1 of 2 possible 8-bit values? If so which ones are they?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, boolean, language-lawyer, bit-representation

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29809949/5825294) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75436023/can-an-uninitialized-bool-compare-different-to-both-0-and-1).

If I define

```cpp
bool y = true;
bool n = false;
```

is the bit-wise content of the 1-byte storage of `y` and `n` mandated by the standard? If so, which are those two contents? If not, then how is the comparison between `bool`s themselves or between `bool`s and other integer types handled?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types, the size of bool is implementation defined and may not be equal to one. So there is nothing in the standard that says a boolean must be one bit. (not even in bitfields, just that a boolean and its representation in a bitfield must compare equal). And then the standard has a lot to say about conversions to bool (e.g. from int)

Comment: The standard doesn't define how compilers handle things internally. `true` has to be equal to all other `true` values, just like `0.0` has to be equal to `0.0` (even on systems which have signed zero, and therefore two bit patterns that both represent zero).

Answer (score 3):

Standard does not require any bit representation for `bool`, it only requires that there are two values `true` and `false` - and in particular, it doesn't seem to require that there is only one representation for each value ([[basic.fundamental]#10](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#10)):

> Type `bool` is a distinct type that has the same object representation, value representation, and alignment requirements as an implementation-defined unsigned integer type.
> The values of type `bool` are `true` and `false`.

It is required that `true` is mapped to `1` and `false` is mapped to `0` when converting `bool` to `int` ([[conv.prom]#6](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom#6)):

> A prvalue of type `bool` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int`, with `false` becoming zero and `true` becoming one.

Comment: "Same value representation" sounds a bit weird in context. There's no unsigned integer type with values `true` or `false`, so how can `bool` have the same value representation?

Comment: @MSalters I can't say I understand it fully, but the same is used to refer to unsigned vs signed types and they only have partly overlapping set of values. It seems that if the unsigned type would have values `true` and `false` for some reason, they would be the same, but since the value sets are non-overlapping, this part doesn't apply.

Comment: @MSalters https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.types.general#def:representation,value

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Tricky that. It means that `bool` has the same number of value and padding bits as that other type, so it can't be 1+7.

Comment: @MSalters When we talk about *value representation*, then we are not talking about *values*, but about the bit patterns that represent the values. Hence, there is no weirdness.