# Variables have values after declaring them

Tags: c++

Im just starting to learn c++ and I've run into a little problem. After declaring variables they have value assigned to them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream d ("d.txt");
ofstream r ("r.txt");

int plotas (int a, int b);

int main()
{
    int p,
        a,
        n,
        x1,
        x2,
        y1,
        y2,
        s,
        s1;
    d >> p >> a;
    d >> n;
    for(int i =0; i < n; i++){
        d >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2;
        s+= plotas((x2-x1), (y2-y1));
    }
    s1= plotas(p, a)- s;
    cout << s1;
}
int plotas (int a, int b){
    return a*b;
}
```

For example variable s is 1967866170. Shouldn't they all be 0? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: local atomic (i.e. not classes) variables are not initialized, unless you do it. therefore they may contain a garbage value, and you usually get some warning.

Comment: Zero is hardly "no value". It's very definitely a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local variables that are not assigned any values have what is called [Indeterminate Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423673/what-is-indeterminate-value) ( also known as Garbage Value, it is the value that was previously stored in that memory location ( in c and c++) ) and accessing uninitialized variables leads to Undefined Behavior.

If you do not assign them a value, they will be having the garbage value.

But `static` and global variables have default value as 0

Comment: See Kerrek's comment.

Comment: @jxh , it's undefined Behavior, I admit that. But this is the general answer. The OP asks why the variables have a value after declaring them, and this is the answer.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your answer, Arun, and I've voted it up accordingly

Comment: Thanks. What would be the tidiest way to set them all to  0?

Comment: Your not wrong but it might not be useful in this case

Comment: @PoVa , `variable(0);`

Comment: @PoVa it can be `int x=0;` and also `int x(0);` the 2nd must be in the declaration line.

Comment: To nitpick, the correct term for "garbage value" is indeterminate value.

Comment: Yes, you are correct @chris , Indeterminate value is the correct term, but it's just that people are more familiar with the term garbage value.

Answer (score 3):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization

> Default initialization is performed in three situations:
>
> **1) when a
>   variable with automatic, static, or thread-local storage duration is
>   declared with no initializer**.
>
> 2) when an object with dynamic storage
>   duration is created by a new-expression with no initializer or when an
>   object is created by a new-expression with the initializer consisting
>   of an empty pair of parentheses (until C++03).
>
> 3) when a base class or
>   a non-static data member is not mentioned in a constructor initializer
>   list and that constructor is called.

---

> The effects of default initialization are:
>
> If T is a non-POD (until C++11) class type, the constructors are considered and subjected to overload resolution against the empty
>   argument list. The constructor selected (which is one of the default
>   constructors) is called to provide the initial value for the new
>   object.
>
> If T is an array type, every element of the array is default-initialized.
>
> **Otherwise, nothing is done: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate
>   values.**

Answer (score 0):

Accessing uninitialized variables will lead to [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259885/why-do-i-see-strange-values-when-i-print-uninitialized-variables).

You need to initialize 's' before performing the addition assignment s+= plotas((x2-x1), (y2-y1)).

Answer (score 0):

Simply initialise the variables to prevent them from assuming any garbage value:

```
int p=0, a=0,n=0,x1=0,x2=0,y1=0,y2=0,s=0,s1=0;
```

You can also initialise them to any `int` other than `0` as your code desires.