# C++ initializes value for variable even though I left it empty, why does this happen?

Tags: c++, initialization

For some reason, the value of `final_sum` is 16 but I didn't **initialize** a value for that variable, why's that? Isn't supposed to start with `0`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, sum, final_sum;

    cout<<"ff: "<<final_sum<<endl;
    cout<<"Input the value for n: ";
    cin>>n;

    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        sum += i;
        final_sum += sum;
        cout<<"sum: "<<sum<<endl;
        cout<<"final sum: "<<final_sum<<endl<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The value of an uninitialized variable can be anything. It's also undefined behaviour to read it's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't initialize a variable before reading/using it, its `undefined behavior`. Its value can then be anything, it's unpredictable and always a bad idea. Use

```
int final_sum = 0;
```

to initialize it.

From [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/book/uninitialized):

> The value in an uninitialized variable can be anything – it is
> unpredictable, and may be different every time the program is run.
> Reading the value of an uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour
> – which is always a bad idea. It has to be initialized with a value
> before you can use it.

and

> The only place where they are useful is when you are about to read the
> variable in from some input stream.

Edit : Some may ask "Why my variable still print `0` even though I haven't initialize it?"

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180417/what-happens-when-i-print-an-uninitialized-variable-in-c) post :

> That is because variables with automatic storage duration are not
> automatically initialized to zero in C++. In C++, you don't pay for
> what you don't need, and automatically initializing a variable takes
> time (setting to zero a memory location ultimately reduces to machine
> intruction(s) which are then translated to electrical signals that
> control the physical bits).

So when you do :

```
int final_sum;
```

The `final_sum` is just being reserved a memory location, and anything currently inside that location will be printed out by `cout`. It just happened that there's a big `0` in that spot.

More info : [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior)

Comment: *If you don't initialize a variable, its undefined behavior* - This is not correct. Having an uninitialized variable is OK unless you're trying to read its value before initialization.

Comment: @Evg ah, I'll modified it.

Answer (score 5):

> Isn't supposed to start with 0

No, its initial value is undefined. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization

> the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate values.

If you do

```
 int final_sum{};
```

Or

```
 int final_sum = 0;
```

You will have a `0` in your variable.

---

I suggest you to use `-Wuninitialized` (or better `-Wall`). The compiler will raise a warning if you forgot and initialization

Comment: @soup If you figured it out, click the checkmark next to the most helpful answer to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the variable globally does the job

```
int final_sum;
int main() {
     your code ...
}
```

is the same as

```
int final_sum = 0;
int main() {
    your code here ...
}
```

However, you probably don't want to use global variables and it is always recommended to initialize variables with some value.