# How do I output the max int from user input?

Tags: c++, while-loop, integer

I wrote a program that should output the maximum `int` from user input:

```
15 20 0 5 -1
```

should output `Max: 20`

There seems to be an infinite loop because it never gets to the final `cout` statement. The while loop should stop with a negative number. It's not outputting anything right now.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int currV;
    int maxSoFar;

    // 15 20 0 5 -1

    // should output 20

    cin >> currV;
    if (currV > 0)
    {
        maxSoFar = currV;
    }

    while (currV > 0)
    {

        if (currV > maxSoFar)
        {
            maxSoFar = currV;
        }
        cin >> currV;
    }
    cout << "Max: " << maxSoFar;
}
```

Comment: It should end the while loop when it hits -1 in the user input

Comment: Well, then you should change the condition of your while loop, because as it is it'll also exit when the user enters `0`. Right now I have the opposite problem you describe: Instead of the code looping forever, it exits prematurely on your input.

Comment: [`std::cout << "Max: " << *std::max_element(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),{});](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64ede3084d5f5e4b)

Comment: @MooingDuck "*The while loop should stop with a negative number*" - using `istream_iterator` like you show will not end on a negative number, only on EOF

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I recommend formatting your code better.

Furthermore, your code looks quite confusing and I recommend something like this for what you are trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int currV = 0;
    int maxSoFar = 0;

    while (cin >> currV)
    {
        if(currV < 0)
        {
            cout << "Max: " << maxSoFar;
            return 0;
        }

        if(currV > maxSoFar)
        {
            maxSoFar = currV;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could do `cin >> currV; maxSoFar = currV;` before the `while` loop.  Thus if on one value is entered, it will be the maximum.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: It already works that way, no need to special-case the first item and duplicate code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `maxSoFar`. [Reading/using an uninitialized variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180417/what-happens-when-i-print-an-uninitialized-variable-in-c) will cause [`undefined behaviour`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), then afterward anything could happened. This could be solve by initializing `maxSoFar = -1;` beforehand.

You can use [`max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) to get maximum value of 2 integers as well.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int currV, maxSoFar = -1; //initializing maxSoFar

    while(cin >> currV)
    {
        if (currV < 0) {break;}
        maxSoFar = max(maxSoFar, currV);
    }
    cout << "Max : " << maxSoFar; return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
5 20 0 5 -1
Max : 20
```

Also, see [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Related : [What happens to a declared, uninitialized variable in C? Does it have a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value)

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int currV, maxSoFar = -1;

    if (cin >> currV && currV >= 0)
    {
        maxSoFar = currV;
        while (cin >> currV && currV >= 0)
        {
            if (currV > maxSoFar)
            {
                maxSoFar = currV;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Max: " << maxSoFar;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/5Hg7By)

Comment: Is the enclosing `if` necessary?

Comment: @BenVoigt In this solution `maxSoFar` is initialized in the same line that it's declared.

Comment: @NathanPierson: oops, yeah it is `currV` that is undefined, and never used that way.  However the special-case of first item is still useless, because `>= 0` and `> maxSoFar` are equivalent for the first iteration.

Comment: I initialize `maxSoFar` and added the outer `if` in case the first input is either invalid or negative.

Answer (score 0):

```
int currV;
int maxSoFar = 0; // if all integers are negetive than `maxSoFar` should be 0
 
while (cin >> currV)
{
    if (currV < 0) break;
    maxSoFar = max(maxSoFar, currV);
}
cout << "Max: " << maxSoFar;
```

see this - https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#stream-input-failure