# Variable in one function picks up value from variable in another function

Tags: c++, function, declaration

When I run this cpp code in devC++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <conio.h>

void getdata();
void dis();

void getdata()
{
    int radius;
    cout<<"\n enter radius of circle:-";
    cin>>radius;
}

void dis()
{   
    int rad;
    cout<<"\n num is "<<rad;
}

int main()
{
    //int radius;
    getdata();
    dis();

    getch();
    return 11;
}
```

My output shows:

```
enter radius of circle:-15
radius is 15
```

my question is:
`radius` and `rad` are local to their functions, then how does `rad` became the same value as `radius`? They are in different functions.

Can someone kindly explain what is happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @NickyC Err, why that dupe target?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I see strange values when I print uninitialized variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259885/why-do-i-see-strange-values-when-i-print-uninitialized-variables)

Comment: Try compiling and running it online, you will get different values

Answer (score -1):

**Undefined behavior.**

When `getdata()` is called, `radius` occupies a particular block of memory on the stack, and is populated with the user's input. When `getdata()` exits, that memory block becomes available for later reuse, and its content is not cleared.

When `dis()` is then called afterwards, `rad` is not being initialized, so it picks up whatever random value was already present in the memory block that it occupies.

Most likely, what is happening is that `rad` happens to occupy the same memory block that `radius` had previously occupied. That is why you see the same value. But this is not guaranteed, so don't rely on it.  Add some additional variables above either `radius` or `rad` and you will see different behavior.

Always initialize your variables before you perform operations that are dependent on them.

Answer (score -2):

If the variable is uninitialized it will hold the **garbage value**!.

in your case`rad` will print the garbage value .It may differ every time you compile.